# Sort by price low to high and high to low in product listing magento2

Tags: magento2

I am new in Magento 2. I am using Magento 2.1.1

I want to add custom `price low to high` and `price high to low` in Sort By dropdown in product listing page.

I didn't get toolbar.phtml page. Also I didn't get any stuff regarding this in google.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Create plugins in

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="custom_custom_block_toolbar" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Block\Toolbar" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="custom_catalog_model_config" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Config" />
    </type>

</config>
```

**Step 2:** Create **Config.php** in

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Config.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Model;

class Config
{
    public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
    $options
    ) {

        $options['low_to_high'] = __('Price - Low To High');
        $options['high_to_low'] = __('Price - High To Low');
        return $options;

    }

}
```

**Step 3:** Create **Toolbar.php** in

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Catalog/Block/Toolbar.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Block;

class Toolbar
{

    /**
    * Plugin
    *
    * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject
    * @param \Closure $proceed
    * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
    * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
    */
    public function aroundSetCollection(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $collection
    ) {
    $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
    $result = $proceed($collection);

    if ($currentOrder) {
        if ($currentOrder == 'high_to_low') {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'desc');
        } elseif ($currentOrder == 'low_to_high') {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'asc');
        }
    }

    return $result;
    }

}
```