# Magento 2.2.5 Sort By Price: Low to High and High to Low

Tags: magento2

Need :- Sort by price low to high and high to low in product listing magento2.2.5

we follow this tuto but not working 
[Sort by price low to high and high to low in product listing magento2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40520769/sort-by-price-low-to-high-and-high-to-low-in-product-listing-magento2)

anybody help me ?

Comment: please help anybody

Answer (score 0):

As you mention I follow the same example you found and it didn´t work for me, I did and small change in the aroundSetCollection function, and it looks like following:

```
public function aroundSetCollection(
  \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
  \Closure $proceed,
  $collection
) {
  $currentOrder     = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
  $result            = $proceed($collection);

  if($currentOrder) {
    if($currentOrder == 'high_to_low') {
      $collection->setOrder('price', 'desc');
    } else if($currentOrder == 'low_to_high') {
      $collection->setOrder('price', 'asc');
    } else if ($currentOrder == 'created_at') {
      $collection->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
    }
  }

  return $collection;

}
```

Comment: Your second "else if" would not work in this case. Once the first else if executes successfully, it will skip all others in the same block.

Comment: Hi @AdamMellen yep was a finger mistake, I just edit it